# Connection to <git-host> closed by remote host on idle command prompt

Tags: git, ssh

I can use git just fine, I'm not getting any errors when I push or pull from remotes. This is why all of the other answers about about a connection closed by remote host aren't really helping.

It seems that git hosts (this happens to me whether I'm connecting to my company's stash server or to github.com) close my ssh connection very quickly after I pull or push. For example I did a `git pull -ff` waited a few seconds, then started to type `git checkout develop` and this is what happened:

```
git checkout deveConnection to <git-host> closed by remote host.lopConnection to <git-host> closed by remote host.
```

I've made some recent changes to my `~/.ssh/config` here's what it looks like:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/control-master/%r@%h:%p
HashKnownHosts yes
ForwardAgent yes

# ControlPersist keeps connection for 10 minutes after all jump sessions
# are closed. It sets up a background session for that first one
# that will exit one second after all its children have logged out. You
# can close any window without losing your session until you've close
# them all.
ControlPersist 1440m

Host <internal git>
    IdentityFile <internal-git-ssh-key>
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

I just want to stop having my connections closed so quickly by git remotes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ControlMaster and ControlPath were the culprits, putting those under a host entry for just the servers that needed it fixed my problems.

```
HashKnownHosts yes
ForwardAgent yes

# ControlPersist keeps connection for 10 minutes after all jump sessions
# are closed. It sets up a background session for that first one
# that will exit one second after all its children have logged out. You
# can close any window without losing your session until you've close
# them all.
ControlPersist 1440m

Host <internal git>
    IdentityFile <internal-git-ssh-key>
    StrictHostKeyChecking no

Host <internal hosts needing ControlMaster>
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/control-master/%r@%h:%p
```